# verificar se duas chaves de um dicionario possuem valores iguais

Tags: python, dicionário

olá, tenho um dicionario {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['A', 'C'], 'C': ['A', 'B']}, gostaria de saber se existe algum modo de verificar se por exemplo a chave 'A' e a chave 'C' possuem elementos iguais e quais são eles.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d1 = {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['A', 'C'], 'C': ['A', 'B'], 'D': ['B', 'C']}
```

Para testar igualdade total

```
d1['A']==d1['D']
True

d1['A']==d1['B']
False
```

Ou especificamente para a sua questão, procurando elementos de `A` que estejam em `C`.

```
equals = []

for e in d1['A']:
    if e in d1['C']:
        equals.append(e)

print (equals)
['B']
```

Ou mais pythonicamente em apenas uma linha com list comprehension

```
equals = [equal for equal in d1['A'] if equal in d1['C']]
print (equals)
['B']
```

Comment: Cara desculpa, eu tinha só lido por cima a sua resposta, vou remover a minha.